# Overload a method in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code :

```
document.querySelector('.edit').classList.add('hidden');
```

TypeScript tells me that the object returned by `querySelector` does not have `classList` as a method, with the following error :

> Error TS2094: The property 'classList' does not exist on value of type 'Element'.

When I looked at what querySelector returns, I found that it returns Element. so I had to cast it to HTMLElement to be able to use classList like so :

```
(<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.edit')).classList.add('hidden');
```

but like you might guess, at some point it starts to be counter productive, so I am asking you : Is there any sane way to get the classList from querySelector? Am I doing something wrong ? My guess is that I need to Overload the definition of querySelector.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error in lib.d.ts -- `classList` should be a member of `Element`, not `HTMLElement`, according to the IDL. You can edit lib.d.ts to reflect the change.

In general though, if a method returns e.g. an `Animal` but you know it's a `Dog` in this case, you will need to cast the result.